# Data structure for avoiding frequent pushing/popping when searching for successive minima

Tags: algorithm, optimization, data-structures, language-agnostic, online-algorithm

I'm looking for an [online algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_algorithm) for processing more data than I can reasonably store.

I just want to keep data points `n` where the value `v[n]` is smaller than any later value. (The values are generally increasing.)

The obvious way to do this (not to say the only way, or the right way) is to use a stack. For each new point, pop points off the stack while their values are more than the current point's value and then push the current point onto the stack.

But the data is very sparse. In a quick test only about 3 MB were saved per TB.

Comment: It's not completely clear to me what you're asking. If you want to keep the smallest `k` values, while receiving values successively, you should use a priority queue, not a stack. Priority queues are usually implemented as a heap. To keep the smallest `k` values, use a max-heap.

Comment: @Stef Consider 1, 10, 2, 20, 30, 7, 100. You keep 1, 2, 7, and 100 because none of them are followed by a smaller number. If you had all of the numbers in memory, you'd just go through the list backward and output successively smaller numbers. But because the list is terabytes or petabytes long that's not feasible.

Comment: IMHO, the question is not clear: in the first line, you say, "...for processing more data than I can _reasonably store_"; but in the last one, you say, "... only about 3 MB were saved per TB".  3 MB can be _easily_ stored, no?

Comment: @Someone The difficulty is with the TB/EB of data passing through, not the tiny amount that is saved. Just looking for a good structure (or algorithm) to use that will cope well with this much data going through it.

Comment: @Charles, I think you cannot do better than `O(n)` for processing (i.e., "TB/EB of data passing through") since you need to go over the entire input data.

Comment: @Someone Clearly. The data is coming in unstructured, so that's guaranteed. But that doesn't mean that I need to write it all to my data structure, nor that my data structure needs to be naive. My current algorithm writes each value and then pops values off one by one, making 3n reads (once from input, twice from data) and n writes. But writing is expensive and very few of those writes are needed.

Comment: @Someone If you think that a stack is the best structure, my algorithm is optimal, and the best way to optimize is to get a processor with a big cache, you can post that as an answer. But I'd like to see what else might be out there. The current process seems very wasteful for me and my problem seems typical enough that this must have been studied or coded before.

Comment: If the data stream is on its last leg of only increasing values, it is clear you need all those individual pushes along the way. We cannot save on that. However, if the data is such that a rare *descending* value is going to lead to a lot of pops -- i.e. the data has huge downward spikes -- then consider a binary search in the stack (array-like) to find the spot from where the stack should be clipped in one operation. But only perform it when it is already established the value is descending (less than the stack's top value)

Comment: The stack is the right way.  It's amortized O(1) time per value, and no other online algorithm could use less memory.

Answer (score 1):

You could process the data in chunks. Define the size of a chunk such that the expected result size is guaranteed to fit in it. So if we say ten million of values are considered a chunk, then we are also saying the number of minima will never exceed 10 million. Then proceed as follows:

- Reserve an array for storing 10 million values
- As long as there is more data, keep repeating the following steps
- Populate the free part of the array with input values
- Go backwards through the whole array to find the minima. As you noted this can be done without stack. It can be done *inplace* in the array, by saving the found minima at the right side of the array.
- Move the those minima to the *start* of the array, leaving a free part at the right side of the array, which can be populated in the next iteration with new input values.

At the end you'll have the minima at the start of the array.

This can be optimised by stopping the backwards iteration when arriving in the part of the array that contains the previous iteration's result, and the value to compare with is also from that part. The part at the right of the array should then be moved just after this point in the array.

This algorithm *could* run faster than your stack version, assuming that reading a chunk of input data in an array can be done very fast, and that moving a part of an array to the left can also be done very fast (memcopy type of action).